# Getting "raise WebDriverException" running Selenium Python for Firefox on Windows 7

Tags: python, windows, firefox, selenium

I am continuously getting Python errors while trying to execute the following simple Selenium Python code for Firefox on Windows 7 system.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
```

I couldn't find any previous questions related to Windows and thus I'm trying to see if anyone can help me solve this issue.

I've uninstalled Python 3.4 and installed the latest Python 3.5 to no avail.

Here's the error message in its entirety:

> =============== RESTART: C:\PythonScripts\selenium\firefox.py =============== Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\PythonScripts\selenium\firefox.py", line 4, in 
>       driver = webdriver.Firefox()   File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py",
>   line 78, in **init**
>       self.binary, timeout)   File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\extension_connection.py",
>   line 51, in **init**
>       self.binary.launch_browser(self.profile, timeout=timeout)   File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_binary.py",
>   line 68, in launch_browser
>       self._wait_until_connectable(timeout=timeout)   File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_binary.py",
>   line 98, in _wait_until_connectable
>       raise WebDriverException("The browser appears to have exited " selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: The browser
>   appears to have exited before we could connect. If you specified a
>   log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details.

- Python version is 3.5.1
- Selenium version is 2.51.0
- Firefox version is 44.0.2
- Windows version is 7 Professional SP1

Appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Have you tried with selenium 2.50 or 2.49? Same issue?

Comment: When I executed "pip install selenium" on Python, it installed Selenium 2.51.0. I have no idea how to downgrade it.

Comment: `pip install selenium==2.50`, for instance.

Comment: Sorry alexce, still the same issue with 2.50 and 2.49. I can see Firefox window come up and then it would die. After that, another Firefox window appears with the above message. It's been going like that for 2 days and I couldn't find any solution on the internet.

Comment: Okay, two more things to try: firefox 43 or older ([link](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/)). Use `driver.get("http://python.org")` instead of `driver.get("http://www.python.org")`.

Comment: Alecxe, it's alright. I've tried to downgrade Firefox to 43 to no avail and I've now got Chrome to work on Selenium Python using Chrome engine. Thanks for your help though. I'm going to use Chrome for testing.